# Is there a Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate for asking for recommendations for dev. books?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to post a request for recommendations on a good book on Swift 2.0. Clearly this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Is there a Stack Exchange site that's a good fit for this sort of question?

Comment: No, there is not an appropriate place on SO to ask this question. There is [this](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md) on Github.

Comment: Well, normally I would send you to look at the tag-wiki, but that's relatively bare for swift2...

Comment: Perhaps a new Area 51 site proposal: Book Recommendations.SE?

Comment: Tag wiki? What tag wiki? By all means, point me to it.

Comment: @DuncanC http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info, I guess